# Android Room sort by alias

Tags: android

I'd like to order my dataset based on a custom alias I created. I tried it, however it results in a syntax error. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
@Query("SELECT a/b as ratio " +
        "FROM dataset " +
        "where my_status = :myStatus " +
        "order by ratio ASC")
```

It can't find ratio in the order by part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `Room` generates your `SQL` queries based on your entities at compile time. So, only column names specified in your entity will be recognisable by `Room`.

For instance, if you have an entity `Employee`:

```
@Entity(tableName = "employee_table")
public class Employee {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private double monthlySalary;
}
```

And you want to calculate yearly or daily wages or something else, then you could add an additional column to `Employee` (`private double mathResult`) and then use it as an alias name:

```
@Dao
public interface EmployeeDao {
    @Query("select firstName, lastName, monthlySalary, monthlySalary*12 as mathResult from user_table order by mathResult asc")
    LiveData<List<Employee>> getUsers();    
}
```