# How can I orderby sum of column in room persistence library?

Tags: android, android-room

I am developing android application. And I am using room persistence library. I have some problems with query. How can I use renamed (sum as newSum) column in orderby or groupby?

Below are app entities

products:

```
@Entity(tableName = "products")
public class Product {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "price")
    private double price;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "block")
    private int block;

    public Product(String name, double price, int block) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.block = block;
    }

     // getter and setter
}
```

product_orders:

```
@Entity(tableName = "product_orders",
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(entity = Order.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "order_id"),
                @ForeignKey(entity = Product.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "product_id")
        })
public class ProductOrder {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "order_id", index = true)
    private int order_id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_id", index = true)
    private int product_id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "price")
    private double price;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "quantity")
    private int quantity;

    public ProductOrder(int order_id, int product_id, double price, int quantity) {
        this.order_id = order_id;
        this.product_id = product_id;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
```

orders:

```
Entity(tableName = "orders", foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Customer.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "customer_id", onDelete = CASCADE))
public class Order {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "customer_id", index = true)
    private int customer_id;
    @TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "created_at")
    private Date created_at;

    public Order(int customer_id, Date created_at) {
        this.customer_id = customer_id;
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }
```

dao:

```
@Query("SELECT products.name, " +
            "SUM(products.price * product_orders.quantity) as sum, " +
            "SUM(product_orders.quantity) as quantity " +
            "FROM product_orders " +
            "INNER JOIN products ON product_orders.product_id = products.id " +
            "WHERE product_orders.order_id IN (:mList) " +
            "GROUP BY product_orders.product_id " +
            "ORDER BY sum DESC " +
            "LIMIT 5")
    List<Products> getProducts(List<Integer> mList);
```

How can I ordering query by sum of columns? I try above code but it give an error in this line

```
"ORDER BY sum DESC "
```

cannot resolve symbol sum

Comment: Can you add code of your entity?

Comment: @NatigBabayev OK

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51149665/11016588